# Change css on model validation error

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm aware of **input-validation-error** class added to elements bound to the model.
But what if my input field is styled and wrapped with div:

```
<div class="inputWide">
    <span class="inputWideSpan"></span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "wide" })
</div>
```

I would like to change/add styles to the inputWide div on the Model.FirstName validation fail to change background etc, is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a plugin like [jQuery Validate Hooks](https://gist.github.com/957732)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on whether the validation is client or server side. Better to do something like:

```
<div class="inputWide">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CardNumber)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "wide" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
</div>
```

With css:

```
.field-validation-error 
{
    display: block;
    color: #ff0000;
}
.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
} 
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}
.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

Which will render something similar to:

[image: results]

Comment: isn't that same thing and on validation failure additional css class will be added to the input field itself ?

Comment: but I'm interested on adding a css class to a wrapping div.

Comment: did you add any css yourself or those classes came with the project?